# How to pass a php variable in shell then have the value of return on my page html?

Tags: php, html, bash

How to pass a php variable in shell then have the value of return on my page html?

Here is my code that does not return anything in my html page:

My bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Hello $UserName"
```

My html with php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Project</title>
  <style>

  </style>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
     if(isset($_POST['submit']))
     {
       $UserName = $_POST['UserName'];
       $output = shell_exec("script.sh $UserName");
       echo $output; //doesn’t work
    }
    ?>


    <form action="" method="post">
    <input type = "text" name = "UserName" >
    <input type = "submit" name="submit" value="Launch">
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: doesn’t work? or returns just `Hello`? In bash you would use `$1` not `$UserName` also your code is wide open to [command injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Command_Injection).

Answer (score 0):

When you pass arguments to a shell script, you need to access them like `"$1"`, `"$2"`, etc.

So your shell script should be:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Hello $1"
```

Apart from that you should escape your argument to avoid injection:

```
$output = shell_exec("script.sh " . escapeshellarg($UserName));
```

Also note that `shell_exec()` does not provide much to help you trouble-shoot. You might want to use [`exec()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) instead.